# Can't push to Github using SSH

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am trying to push to my remote git repository that I cloned using SSH, but I can't push to it. I get the following error:

> fatal: Remote end hung up unexpectedly

I have done some searching and found that most people had to do `git config ssh.postBuffer 524288000`, but this has not worked for me; I still get the same error.

I am running my local repository on Levinux (because my university course requires it). I generated my SSH key and added it to GitHub already. Connecting using https works, but I'd rather use SSH. Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that your SSH key from the machine you are using is not associated with your GitHub account. A way to verify this is to run the command

```
ssh git@github.com
```

If you see output along the lines of

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi rdthomson! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
```

then your key is configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks Greg! Tried generating the SSH key on a different machine and it worked so there must be something odd with the SSH key that was generated on the Levinux machine we have to use.

Comment: @rdthomson You're welcome! I'm glad my suggestion helped.

Comment: @rdthomson Which format (dsa | ecdsa | ed25519 | rsa | rsa1) and how many bits in each key?

Answer (score 9):

For me, once I got the key to show up in the `Help>Show SSH Key` dialog box and

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

was working fine; however when I ran

```
git remote -v
```

I could see that the repo was cloned from the `https://github.com/` URL; not `ssh://git@github.com/`

```
origin https://github.com/User/Project.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/User/Project.git (push)
```

So, I had to do

```
git remote set-url --push origin 'git@github.com:User/Project.git'
```

and then Git GUI and TUI were both pushing just fine.